# hierarchical relationship in php for menu

Tags: php, mysql

We have hierarchical relationship in a table like this

table name: category

```
 id       parent_id    title
  1         0           main menu
  2         1           sub_menu1
  3         2           sub_sub_menu1
```

another table: domain

```
id        cat_id        name
 1           1           main domain
 2           2           sub domain
 3           3           sub sub domain
```

We are trying to show category and subcategory 
As my friend suggested its too complex and too costly to show this type of relation-ship via sql so we moved to show this via php.

We wrote this code:-

```
function getSubCatCount($data,$parent){
    $count=0;
    $count =$count+ domainCatCount($parent);
    return $count;
}


function menuList($data, $parent = 0,$st )
{
    static $i = 0;
    $tab = str_repeat(" ",$i);
    if($data[$parent])
    {
    $html .= "";
    $i++;


    if($i==1)
                $html .= '<ul data-menu="main" class="menu__level">';
    else{
                $html .= '<ul data-menu="submenu-'.$parent.'" class="menu__level">';
    }
    $tmpLis="";
        foreach($data[$parent] as $v)
        {
            $html .= '<li class="menu__item"><a href="#" class="menu__link ';
            $child = menuList($data, $v['id'],"false");
            $html .= '" data-submenu="submenu-'.$v['id'].'" ';      
            //if(!$child)
            {
                $tmpLis.=domainHtmlList($v['id']);
            }
            $html .= '>';


            $html .= $v['title'].'<div style="float: right;"><table style="width: 145px;"><tr><td style="width: 30%;"><img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/metro-explorer/512/my_location-512.png"  style="width: 20px;height: 20px;" title="usages">'.getUsages($v['id']).'</td><td style="width: 30%;"><img src="http://www.clubs.uci.edu/cae/a/src/1432405005258.png"  style="width: 20px;height: 20px;" title="domains">'.getDomainCount($data,$v['id']).'</td><td style="width: 30%;"><img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/flat-ui-icons-24-px/24/eye-24-128.png"  style="width: 20px;height: 20px;" title="views">'.getViews($v['id']).'</td></tr></table></div></a></li>';
//if (preg_match_all('/<[a-z \'"]*data-menu=[\'"]submenu-'.$v['id'].'[\'"][^>]*>([^<]*)/i', $html, $matches)) {
    //print_r($matches);
    //$child = menuList($data, $v['id'],"true");
//$html .= $child;
//} 

        }
            if($st!="true")
            $html .= "</ul>";
            $html .=$tmpLis;
        foreach($data[$parent] as $v)
        {
            $child = menuList($data, $v['id'],"false");
            if($child)
            {
                $i–;
                $html .= $child;
            }
        }
        return $html;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}



function domainHtmlList($i){
global $db; 

$domainCatRows = $db->getRows("SELECT * FROM  `url_domain` WHERE  `category` ='".$i."'");
if(count($domainCatRows)>0)
    $html = '<ul data-menu="submenu-'.$i.'" class="menu__level">';
foreach($domainCatRows as $ff) 
{
$dom=$ff['domain'];
$count=0;
if($ff['domain']=="[[[main_url]]]")
$dom="123.yt";
$html .= '<li class="menu__item"><a href="#" class="menu__link ';
    $html .=  'submenu-child" data-key="'.$ff['id'].'" data-domain="'.$dom.'" ';
$html .= '>';
$domainId=$ff['id'];
    //for usages
    $shortUrlRows = $db->getRows("SELECT count(*) as usages_count FROM `shorturl` WHERE `urlDomainId` in (".$domainId.") ");
    foreach($shortUrlRows as $val) 
    {
        $count=$count+$val['usages_count']; 
    }   
    //for views
    //$tmp= $db->getRows("SELECT count(*) as count FROM  `stats` WHERE  `url` like '%".$dom."%'");  
    //echo "SELECT * FROM  `stats` WHERE  `reffer` like '%".$dom."%'"."<br/>";
    //print_r($tmp);

    $tmp= $db->getRows("SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id SEPARATOR ',') as shortUrlDomain FROM  `shorturl` WHERE  `urlDomainId` in (".$domainId.")");
    //echo "SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id SEPARATOR ',') as shortUrlDomain FROM  `shorturl` WHERE  `urlDomainId` in (".$domainId.")"."<br/>";
    $tmpsts= $db->getRows("SELECT count(*) as count FROM  `stats` WHERE  `page_title` in (".$tmp[0]['shortUrlDomain'].")");
    //echo "SELECT count(*) as count FROM  `stats` WHERE  `page_title` in (".$tmp[0]['shortUrlDomain'].")"."<br/>";
    //$count=$count+$tmpsts[0]['count'];        

     $html .="<div style='float:right;'><table style='width: 140px;'><tr><td style='width: 30%;'><img src='https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/metro-explorer/512/my_location-512.png'  style='width: 20px;height: 20px;' title='usages'>".$count."</td><td style='width: 30%;'><img src='https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/flat-ui-icons-24-px/24/eye-24-128.png'  style='width: 20px;height: 20px;' title='views'>".$tmpsts[0]['count']."</td></tr></table></div>";
   $html .= $dom.'</a>';
            $html .='</li>';
    }
if(count($domainCatRows)>0)
$html .= "</ul>";
return $html;
}
```

Now the problem is when we have subcategory and domain both in one category its not showing both. Its only showing either sub-category or domain. We tried all the things but none of working. So how we show this type of relationship?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to everyone who has that problem to use 'Nested Tree Model'.

Create 2 new int columns (lft and rgt) in you categories table and fill them with the values provided by the algorithm (Just read some documentation, it isn't hard to understand).
Once this is done, you can get all main Categories with this query:

```
SELECT * FROM categories WHERE parent_id = 0 OR parent_id IS NULL
```

Now, for every main category, get all her childs.

```
SELECT * FROM categories 
WHERE lft >= (
      SELECT lft FROM categories
      WHERE id = {$id}
) AND rgt <= (
      SELECT rat FROM categories
      WHERE id = {$id}
)
ORDER BY lft;
```

Wikipedia helps me a lot with the algorithm:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model

In addition, there are some php libraries, like this one.
http://www.sideralis.org/baobab/

I hope it will help you,

Regards.